# How does a body heat up?

Tags: thermal-radiation

Suppose a block of metal B is in a vacuum chamber at room temp (27°C) and we irradiate it at 77*C

[image]

Can anyone explain what happens step by step in B, and how actually its temperaure rises? DO the oncoming photons interact only with electrons or protons or are there other more complex direct interactions?

Because of the low energy of the photons(.03 eV) these cannot knockoff or excite electrons or nuclei, so the only possible outcome seems *Thomson scattering*, in which the photon rebounds losing very little energy, and the electron gains at most an acceleration of a few m/s. Is this correct so far?

Can you now explain how this first impact evolves and produces phonons and the gradual increase of temperature up to 350K?